# KSQL Server Elastic Scaling in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ksqldb

in the context of kubernetes or else, does it make sense to have one KSQL SERVER per application? When i read the capacity planning for KSQL Server, it is seems the basic settings are for running multiple queries on one server. 
However I feel like to have a better control over scaling up and down with Kubernetes, it would make more sense to fix the number of Thread by per query, and launch a server configured in kube with let say 1 cpu, where only one application would run. However i am not sure how heavy are KSQL Server, and if that make actual sense or not.

Any recommendation.

Comment: In my Kafka Streams applications (KSQL is built on Kafka Streams) I use container orchestrators to manage and scale-in/scale-out my applications. This is because I clearly separate different stages and concerns of my application logic, microservices style. The thing is that KSQL Server is different.. you could do the same, but with extra overhead of running a ton of KSQL Servers Instances to handle all your applications.

Comment: Anyway, you can deploy your KSQL Server Instances as containers, managed in a container orchestrator. You can define to which cluster (KSQL_SERVICE_ID) it will join and where can he bootstrap from (ie: other instances of the cluster). With this mechanism, you can orchestrate several KSQL Clusters (i.e: per application, as you mentioned) and scale-in/scale-out each of them independently.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you have mentioned is clearly doable. You can [run KSQL Server with Docker](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/install-ksql-with-docker.html), so it's you could have a container orchestrator such as kubernetes or swarm maintaining and scheduling those KSQL Server instances.

So you know how this would play out:

1. Each KSQL Instance will join a group of other KSQL Instances with
   the same `KSQL_SERVICE_ID` that use the same Kafka Cluster defined by `KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`
2. You can create several KSQL Server Clusters, i.e for different
   applications, just use different `KSQL_SERVICE_ID` while using the
   same Kafka Cluster.

As a result, you now you have:

1. Multiple Containerized KSQL Server Instances managed by a container
   orchestrator such as Kubernetes.
2. All of the KSQL Instances are connected to the Same Kafka Cluster (you can also have different Kafka Clusters for different `KSQL_SERVICE_ID`)
3. The KSQL Server Instances can be grouped in different applications
   (different `KSQL_SERVICE_ID`) in order to achieve separation of
   concerns so that scalability, security and availability can be
   better maintained.

Regarding the coexistence of several KSQL Server Instances (maybe with different `KSQL_SERVICE_ID`) on the same server,  you should know the available machine resources can be monopolized by a greedy instance, causing problems to the less greedy instance. With Kubernetes you could set resource limits on your Pods to avoid this, but greedy instances will be limited and slowed down.

Confluent [advice regarding multi-tenancy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/capacity-planning.html#general-guidelines):

> We recommend against using KSQL in a multi-tenant fashion. For
>   example, if you have two KSQL applications running on the same node,
>   and one is greedy, you're likely to encounter resource issues related
>   to multi-tenancy. We recommend using a single pool of KSQL Server
>   instances per use case. You should deploy separate applications onto
>   separate KSQL nodes, because it becomes easier to reason about scaling
>   and resource utilization. Also, deploying per use case makes it easier
>   to reason about failovers and replication.

A possible drawback is the overhead you'll have if you run multiple KSQL Server Instances (Java Application footprint) in the same pool while having no work for them to do (i.e: no schedulable tasks due to lack of partitions on your topic(s)) or simply because you have very little workload. You might be doing the same job with less instances, avoiding idled or nearly-idled instances.

Of course stuffing all stream processing, maybe for completely different use cases or projects, on a single KSQL Server or pool of KSQL Servers may bring its own internal concurrency issues, development cycle complexities, management, etc..

I guess something in the middle will work fine. Use a pool of KSQL Server instances for a single project or use case, which in turn might translate to a pipeline consisting on a topology of several source, process and sinks, implemented by a number of KSQL queries.

Also, don't forget about the scaling mechanisms of Kafka, Kafka Streams and KSQL (built on top of Kafka Streams) discussed in the [previous question you've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926562/ksql-query-number-of-thread/56926770#56926770).

All of this mechanisms can be found here:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/capacity-planning.html
https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/concepts/ksql-architecture.html
https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/install-ksql-with-docker.html